# How to remove Section according to indexpath in CollectionView in swift?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

my functionality is when i remove on close button section and data also be removed from indexpath.

i have taken UICollelctionReusableView for Section.

section count is according to array of number of Apple Data.

i have attached image

[image: Header]

and data is attached to header
like header and one row.

i want to remove section and row when i tap on close button.
can anyone help me to findout solution?

sample code

```
  var index:NSIndexPath = sender.tag
    array.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row())
    self.coll.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths([sender.tag])
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to remove the entire section, it should be something like this:

```
let section = sender.tag
array.removeAtIndex(section)
collectionView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: section))
```

Given that all the section data is inside `array[section]`.